# Chess Boxing - Wondering how I would do / how I'd get into it

Tags: boxing, mixed-martial-arts

Ok I tried to find the 'chess boxing' subforum here and one doesn't exist, but I'm not surprised it's not by any means mainstream. Hopefully there's someone here that is knowledgeable and I'd appreciate it if you could answer this even theoretically.

I have 2 questions

1. Do I even have the skills necessary to think about competing?
2. If I do how would I get into it?

To expand on 1)

- **For boxing:** I'm quite heavyset, I'm over 250 lbs easily and would definitely be competing at heavyweight. I could possibly get my weight down to
  200 but I'd be throwing knockout punches, I'm far more of a slugger/brawler than a technical boxer unfortunately. I have very little experience in pure boxing but train muay thai a few times a week. It should also be noted that I'm not that young early 30s and there are many many people that are far better at boxing than I am. In fact I just do some sparring at my gym that's about my level NEVER have I stepped in a ring or actually competed.
- **For chess:** As far as chess skills go, I LOVE chess I'm about 1400 FIDE and used to be a member of various chess clubs (university and high school) but by no means would I consider myself an expert and 1600 level which if the chess boxing websites are to be believed is the minimum rating to compete. I have competed in MANY chess tournaments but by no means would I consider myself the 1600 level FIDE that is listed which imo is someone that has extensive experience with openings and theory and is very talented.

Would I even have a chance as a very big dude with a knockout punch that loves chess but is by no means an expert in boxing nor chess?

Comment: https://youtu.be/E7OFJjhGSX4

Comment: If you have two questions, then please ask **two** questions, not one.

Comment: please ask this on another se site like sports se or chess se. i am so damn curious to see what they have to say XD also damn you really seem to fit the profile of a chessboxer. chess-wise i've seen some of the ELOs/FIDEs of chessboxers in london chessboxing videos and i recall they were like 1400-1899. of course there are some 2000+ people, but i remember this guy who was even just 1100+ Edit: here you go [jon wood ELO 1100](https://www.chessboxing.info/fighter/171220172623) (also see the guy's opponents. i told you 1400-1899!)

Comment: btw re chess (or boxing myb): i notice there are some options to play for a draw in chess to hope to win in the boxing or play defensively in boxing and then win in chess. seen a lot of videos about how usually 1 player is better in chess and the other in boxing. perhaps you might specialise a little more in 1 of them say the chess and then play defensively in the boxing. so idk i wouldn't necessarily think 'NEVER have I stepped in a ring or actually competed' would be a hindrance! but anyhoo this was 2 years ago and same month! did you get into more boxing or something?

Comment: @Sardathrion-againstSEabuse sounds more like a 2-part question than actually 2 questions. or do you disagree?

Answer (score 2):

Working off of the [information here](https://youtu.be/E7OFJjhGSX4), it looks like the two gateway requirements are a minimum of 50 boxing club fights and a minimum ELO rating of 800-1200 (possibly contradicting that, [these rules](https://www.rulesofsport.com/sports/chess-boxing.html) state a minimum rating of 1800). Honestly, based upon the higher rating I found online, and a possible requirement for having actually competed, you may not be qualified. On the other hand, [World Chess Boxing Association](http://worldchessboxing.com/contact/wcba-chessboxing-faq/) rules do not have a minimum rating, so you may be able to compete with them, although their last listed "upcoming event" was in 2018.

Comment: Just as a reference - an ELO rating of 800-1200 is very entry level (White belt to mid colored belt range). 800 really means you know about how the pieces move. 1200 you have a basic idea of tactics/strategies and maybe the first couple moves of a few openings. 1800 is getting into decently high territory, you have a good grasp of a lot of tactics/strategies, know quite a few openings at a high level and have several openings at a very deep level (2-4th degree black belt range).